# glDrawArrays works in vm, crashes on phone

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am drawing a line in opengl es from the Android NDK. I have been developing on the VM's and just recently tried my application on a phone. The application runs fine on the vm's. A line is drawn. However, on a motorola droid, the application just crashes, and on a HTC incredible it just shows a black screen. I have verified that the number being passed to the function are correct. The application haults on the glDrawArray(GL_LINES, 0, 2) call. The whole function looks like this:

```
void drawLine(GLfloat x1, GLfloat y1, GLfloat x2, GLfloat y2, GLfloat * color)
{
    GLfloat vVertices[] =
    {x1, y1,
    x2, y2};

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glColor4f(color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vVertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"to mama","You drew arrays");

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

and the call to it looks like this:

```
drawLine(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,colorx);/*x is green*/
```

I can try drawelements next, but there is not reason draw arrays should not work (as far as i know).

Comment: When you say "it crashes", what happens exactly? Did the log line get written? Can you add more logging or even a simple try/catch, to see what's failing?

Comment: There should be big warnings on the emulator - "WARNING - this is rubbish and will give completely inconsistant and incomplete results when developing OpenGL apps/games. We strongly recommend you perform all development and testing on real phones."  I can only assume it's a little more use when there's no OpenGL in your software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're enabling the color array (`glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)`) without actually setting setting the [`glColorPointer()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glColorPointer.xml).

Either set the color pointer or don't enable the color array.